# Select and display server files

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm using `shell_exec` to execute a command on my server and show the result with echo.

Now, I want to select and display the files displayed. How can I do this?

```
<body>
    <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>">
        <input type="submit" class="reset_button"/>
        <p><b>Search</b></p>
        <?php
            <input type='text' name='idtest' value='' />
            <input type='submit' value='consultar' />
        ?>
        <?php
            $consulta=$_GET[idtest];
            $salida =  shell_exec('find / -iname *'.$consulta.'*|sort');    
            echo "<pre>$salida</pre>";
        ?>
</body>
```

Result from code:

```
text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt
text4.txt
```

Comment: Check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: Do you want to display the contents of the files or the list of file names?

Comment: The contents of the file. The list is displayed Already.

Comment: welcome to SO. If you take a little tour of the questions asked and well answered here, you'll see it is better to post the parts of the code you think must be improved.
Take your time to format and rephrase your question please. also read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $salida =  shell_exec('find / -iname *'.$consulta.'* |sort');

This isn't going to work the way you expect; the `*'.$consulta.'*` will be expanded to match anything in the current directory. It should be `\'*'.$consulta.'*\'`

I'm also struggling to imagine where it would make sense to ever expose such functionality via a webserver - its going to be expensive to search the whole filesystem and potentially exposes a lot of stuff which should not be accessible remotely.

> How can I do this?

If it were me....

```
 <?php
 $consulta=$_GET[idtest];
 $salida = explode("\n", shell_exec('find / -iname \*'.$consulta.'\* | sort'));
 foreach ($salida as $s) {
    if (is_readable($s)) {
       print "<a href='filereader.php?src=" . urlencode($s)
         . "'>" . htmlentities($s) . "</a><br />";
    } else {
       print htmlentities($s) . "<br />";
 }
?>
```

Content of filereader.php should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to display everything:

You could add this snippet below the last one, above `</body>`:

```
<?php
   $consulta=$_GET[idtest];
   $alltext = shell_exec('find / -iname *'.$consulta.'* |sort|xargs -I{} cat {}');    
echo "<pre>$alltext</pre>";
?>
```

Now what you want is a little trickier: just read `$salida` as an array, thusly creating a link per file to a ***`new_page.php`***;

Then on the `new_page.php`:

```
<?php
   $filename=$_GET[filename];
   $onetext = shell_exec('cat '.$filename);    
   echo "<pre>$onetext</pre>";
?>
```